# Contrapositives

Tags: logic

I'm a little bit confused by the contraposition. Suppose we have a statement:
"If number can be divided by 3 ($P$), Then it can also be divided by 9 ($Q$)"

In a book "Discrete mathematics with applications" there is an exercise where the reader must provide a contrapositive to this statement. In the answers section the correct answer is this: "If number can be divided by 9, then it can be divided by 3". But isn't this a simple conversion $Q\rightarrow P$?

By the law of contrapositive:
$P\rightarrow Q\equiv\neg Q\rightarrow\neg P$ which can be translated as "If number can not be divided by 9, then it cannot be divided by 3", which is obviously not true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If that's what the book says, then the book is wrong.

Comment: The statement "If a number is divisible by $3$, then it is divisible by $9$" is equivalent to its contrapositive "If a number is not divisible by $9$, then it is not divisible by $3$". Of course, both statements are not true.

Comment: Logical equivalence has nothing to do with the truth of the statement. It just says that the truth of one is equivalent to the truth of the other.

Comment: It seems that there is confusion between the terms *contrapositive* and *converse*.

Answer (score 1):

> "If number can be divided by 3 ($P$), Then it can also be divided by 9
> ($Q$)"....

This statement is false, e.g. 6 is divisible by 3, and 6 is not divisible by 9.

> By the law of contrapositive: P→Q ≡ ¬Q→¬P which can be translated as
> "If number can not be divided by 9, then it cannot be divided by 3",
> which is obviously not true.

Nothing wrong with that. You can take the contrapositive of a false statement. The contrapositive will also then be false.